# How to edit elements of a 2xn matrix along the rows

Tags: r, if-statement

I am having some issues working a forloop which allows me to take the following matrix:

```
> cd
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] -142.5066 -132.9431
[2,] -161.6038 -166.9276
```

and renaming the elements along the columns. Specifically, I want do the following:

`if cd[1,1] > cd[1,2]` , then I want `cd[1,2] == 'STOP'`
`else cd[1,2]==cd[1,2]`

my code right now for a forloop for K rows is:

```
for(k in 1:2){
    if(cd[1,k]>cd[2,k]){
        cd[2,k]<-'STOP'
    }else{
        cd[2,k]<-cd[2,k]
    }
    print(cd)
}
```

The output is the following:

```
      [,1]               [,2]               
[1,] "-142.50660967154" "-132.943085827163"
[2,] "STOP"             "-166.92760911847" 

     [,1]               [,2]               
[1,] "-142.50660967154" "-132.943085827163"
[2,] "STOP"             "-166.92760911847"
```

Essentially, after running the loop, I want the result to be:

```
> cd
          [,1]      [,2]
[1,] -142.5066 -132.9431
[2,]      STOP      STOP
```

Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

When you have a matrix in r, all the elements have to be the same type. At first, you have all numeric elements, so the first comparison works, but when it makes it "stop", then it makes them all character, and "-3" is less than "-4", characterwise. Your options are to use a dataframe instead of a matrix, or use as.numeric(cd[1,k])...

```
> cd <- matrix(c(-1,-2,-3,-4), nrow = 2)
> for(k in 1:2){
+   if(as.numeric(cd[1,k])>as.numeric(cd[2,k])){
+     cd[2,k]<-'STOP'
+   } else{cd[2,k]<-cd[2,k]}
+   print(cd)
+ }
     [,1]   [,2]
[1,] "-1"   "-3"
[2,] "STOP" "-4"
     [,1]   [,2]  
[1,] "-1"   "-3"  
[2,] "STOP" "STOP"
```

Comment: I think that case works because it's comparing the characters "1" and "2". But this doesn't always work: > `"11" < "2" [1] TRUE` At any rate, if that was true, his code would have worked fine. Adding "as.numeric" makes it work for that reason.

Comment: Comment removed.  I was thinking about the case where one value is a numeric, in which case the numeric is coerced to character....  I love R, but if I could remove one thing, it would be implicit  type coercion.

Answer (score 0):

With a matrix there can be no conflicting data types in a column so the numeric values are coerced to character. If you want separate types, use a data.frame:

```
cd <- matrix(c(-142.5066, -132.9431, -161.6038, -166.9276), nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)
cd[2, ] <- ifelse(cd[1,] > cd[2, ], "STOP", cd[2,])
cd
            [,1]        [,2]       
[1,] "-142.5066" "-132.9431"
[2,] "STOP"      "STOP"
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a loop, you could try the following:

```
cd[cd[,1] > cd[,2]] <- 'STOP'

  [,1]        [,2]       
cd "-142.5066" "-132.9431"
   "STOP"      "STOP"
```